# Различия auto и auto&& внутри диапазонного for цикла

Tags: c++, c++11

Какая разница между 1 и 2? Когда что использовать?

```
for (auto   i : container){} // 1
for (auto&& i : container){} // 2
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13230480/what-does-auto-tell-us

Answer (score 10):

Когда у вас имеется объявление вида

```
auto &&x = initializer;
```

то данная `rvalue` ссылка `&&x` является особенной и носит название `forwarding reference`. Если инициализатор представляет собой `lvalue`, то эта ссылка принимает тип `lvalue` ссылки.

Из стандарта C++ (Document Number: N4296, 7.1.6.4 auto speciﬁer)

> 7. ...Deduce a value for U using the rules of template argument deduction
>      **from a function call (14.8.2.1)**, where P is a function
>      template parameter type and the corresponding argument is the
>      initializer, or L in the case of direct-list-initialization.

И далее  (14.8.2.1 Deducing template arguments from a function cal)

> 3. ...A **forwarding reference** is an rvalue reference to a cv-unqualiﬁed
>      template parameter. If P is a **forwarding reference**
>      and the argument is an lvalue, the type “lvalue reference to A” is
>      used in place of A for type deduction

Что это означает? Это означает, что следующие два объявления будут эквивалентными

```
int x = 0;
auto &&r = x;
```

и

```
int x = 0;
auto &r = x;
```

Ниже приведена демонстрационная программа

```
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    { 
        int x = 0;

        std::cout << "x = " << x << std::endl;

        auto &&r = x;

        r = 10;

        std::cout << "x = " << x << std::endl;
    }

    {
        int x = 0;

        std::cout << "x = " << x << std::endl;

        auto &r = x;

        r = 10;

        std::cout << "x = " << x << std::endl;
    }
}
```

Ее вывод на консоль

```
x = 0
x = 10
x = 0
x = 10
```

Из этого также следует, что когда вы имеете дело с `for` предложением на основе диапазона, и соответствующий итератор, возвращаемый функцией `begin`, или соответствующий указатель, после применения оператора разыменования возвращают lvalue значение исходного объекта (указатели всегда возвращают lvalue значение после разыменования), то вы можете изменить этот исходный объект используя объявление `forwarding reference`.

Например,

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

int main()
{
    {
        int a[] = { 0 };

        std::cout << "a[0] = " << a[0] << std::endl;

        auto &&r = *a;

        r = 10;

        std::cout << "a[0] = " << a[0] << std::endl;
    }

    {
        std::vector<int> v(1);

        std::cout << "v[0] = " << v[0] << std::endl;

        auto &&r = *v.begin();

        r = 10;

        std::cout << "v[0] = " << v[0] << std::endl;
    }
}
```

Вывод программы на консоль:

```
a[0] = 0
a[0] = 10
v[0] = 0
v[0] = 10
```

Поэтому, например, для стандартных контейнеров, которые возвращают из разыменованного итератора ссылку на исходный объект, два подобных объявления `for`  эквиваленны

```
std::vector<int> v { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };

for ( auto &&x : v ) x *= 2;
```

и

```
std::vector<int> v { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };

for ( auto &x : v ) x *= 2;
```

Так как в обоих случаях имеется выведенный тип переменной `x` как `int &`.

Когда же используется объявление вида

```
auto x = initializer;
```

то тип переменной `x` выводится из спецификаторов типа инициализатора, игнорируя ссылки. То есть если даже инициализатор - это ссылочный тип, как, например, `int &`, тип переменной `x` будет `int`, а, следовательно вы не сможете изменить исходный объект, используя эту переменную. Например,

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

int main()
{
    {
        std::vector<int> v{ 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };

        for (int x : v) std::cout << x << ' ';
        std::cout << std::endl;

        for (auto &&x : v) x *= 2;

        for (int x : v) std::cout << x << ' ';
        std::cout << std::endl;
    }

    std::cout << std::endl;

    {
        std::vector<int> v{ 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };

        for (int x : v) std::cout << x << ' ';
        std::cout << std::endl;

        for (auto x : v) x *= 2;

        for (int x : v) std::cout << x << ' ';
        std::cout << std::endl;
    }
}
```

Сравните вывод двух кодовых блоков этой программы

```
1 2 3 4 5
2 4 6 8 10

1 2 3 4 5
1 2 3 4 5
```

Если же `forwarding reference` инициализируется rvalue значением, а не lvalue значением, то rvalue ссылка не будет превращаться в lvalue ссылку.
Ниже показано это различие.

```
#include <iostream>

int f()
{
    static int x;

    return x;
}

int & g()
{
    static int x;

    return x;
}

int main()
{
    {
        auto &&x = f();

        std::cout << "x = " << x << std::endl;

        x = 10;

        std::cout << "x = " << x << std::endl;
        std::cout << "f() = " << f() << std::endl;
    }

    std::cout << std::endl;

    {
        auto &&x = g();


        std::cout << "x = " << x << std::endl;

        x = 10;

        std::cout << "x = " << x << std::endl;
        std::cout << "g() = " << g() << std::endl;
    }
}
```

Вывод программы на консоль

```
x = 0
x = 10
f() = 0

x = 0
x = 10
g() = 10
```

Что касается вопроса,

> Когда что использовать?

то лучше использовать `auto &` если вы хотите изменять  значения в цикле, на которые будет ссылаться ссылка, либо `const auto &`, когда вы используете значения только для чтения. `auto` имеет смысл использовать для фундаментальных типов, например, арифметических типов или указателей), когда копирование объекта в создаваемую локальную переменную не является ресурсо-затратной операцией и не требуется изменить исходные объекты.

Comment: @VladD Спасибо, что заметили.

Comment: Что-то я не вижу термина "forwarding reference" в Стандарте.

Comment: @alexolut Я уточнил, на какой рабочий проект стандарта я ссылаюсь, в своем ответе.

Answer (score 6):

Выбирать нужно в зависимости от контекста, о котором Вы совершенно не обмолвились. Например, следующий код:

```
#include <vector>

int main()
{
    std::vector<bool> v;

    for (auto   i: v) { }
    for (auto&  i: v) { } // ошибка
    for (auto&& i: v) { }
}
```

даст ошибку для `auto&`, т.к. `vector<bool>` использует вспомогательный ссылочный класс, *rvalue*-объект которого не может быть связан с неконстанной ссылкой. Из-за прокси-класса возникает ещё одна интересная ситуация, что модификация `i` в циклах `auto` и `auto&&` будут вести себя одинаково, т.е. [изменять значение](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/lQF69oIqa10QHcRj), хранимое в контейнере.

Если вместо `std::vector<bool>` использовать `std::vector<int>`, то `auto` позволит [менять только локальную переменную](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/PVkXCgz1Es9iyCyQ), а `auto&&` (как и `auto&`) уже само значение в контейнере.

Comment: Вот сколько тонкостей надо держать в голове, чтобы писать надежные программы на С++.

Comment: А какие еще типы, кроме bool, в векторе используют прокси-класс?

Comment: @Majestio специализация только для bool, для оптимизации по памяти. Один элемент проецируется на один бит.

Comment: @alexolut , пасип, не знал!

Comment: @älёxölüt можно узнать как  std::vector<bool> примерно реализован, в стандартной библиотеке черт ногу сломит.

Comment: @StanislavPetrov если примерно, то для каждого элемента используется один бит.

Comment: @älёxölüt как там получается вот это "vector<bool> использует вспомогательный ссылочный класс, rvalue-объект которого не может быть связан с неконстанной ссылкой"

Comment: @StanislavPetrov минимальная единица адресации в C++ - это байт. Поэтому нужно городить всякие прокси типы дабы попытаться сослаться на конкретный бит.

Comment: @älёxölüt можно в ответ код добавить? мне интересно как там получается rvalue-объект, в каком месте.

Comment: @StanislavPetrov получается из-за того, что возвращается временный объект. Вот [код](https://wandbox.org/permlink/N5MMUGJxKzigCjiu) для понимания сути.

Answer (score 0):

В первом случае идет перебор по значению, т.е. Вы не можете изменять элементы.

Во втором случае - по универсальной ссылке. т.е. во втором случае можно писать код вида:

```
for (auto&& i : container){ ++i;}
```

Comment: в первом случае тоже можно так писать

Comment: @user230909 только какой смысл в (1) так писать? Хороший компилятор кстати ошибку должен выдать.

Comment: @pavel на каком основании ошибку?

Comment: Написать можно и в первом :), только бестолку. А во втором достаточно `for(auto& i...` - так почему именно два `&&`? :)

Comment: @Harry собственно в этом и цимес

Comment: два && нужно для того, что бы можно было работать как с lvalue так и с rvalue ссылками.

Answer (score -1):

Разницы никакой.
Универсальная ссылка в цикле for используется чтобы код был совместим с контейнерами, итератор которых возвращает rvalue ссылки.

```
template<typename C>
void interate1(C& container) //Non-const
{
    for(auto& v: container)
    {
        //Do something with v
    }
}

template<typename C>
void iterate2(C& conatiner)
{
    for(auto&& v: container)
    {
        //Do soemthign with v
    }
}

...
std::vector<bool> v(10);
iterate1(v); //Error
iterate2(v); //OK
```